# C++ - Concatenating strings (like PHP?)

Tags: c++, string

I've looked around and I haven't found a good answer.

I have files like this: `text1.txt text2.txt text3.txt`

user wants to specify which file to open:

```
int x;
string filename;
cout << "What data file do you want to open? (enter an int between 1 -> 3): ";
cin >> x;
filename = "P3Data" << x << ".txt" ; //does not compile

myfile.open(filename);
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the streaming interface, you need a `stringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream filename;
filename << "P3Data" << x << ".txt";

myfile.open( filename.str().c_str() );
```

Otherwise, you can concatenate two `strings` using **+**.

Comment: If `myfile` is an `ifstream`, I suppose you might want `filename.str().c_str()`.

Comment: @Vlad: Unless this is C++11. Anyway `.c_str()` will work in both C++03 and C++11.

Comment: I didn't know they fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you can say it like this:

```
#include <string>

const std::string filename = std::string("P3Data") + std::to_string(x) + std::string(".txt");
```

If you don't have C++11, you can use `boost::lexical_cast`, or string streams, or `snprintf`. Alternatively, you could just read from `std::cin` into a string rather than an integer.

(If you read into an integer, surround the read with a conditional check to verify the operation: `if (!(std::cin >> x)) { /* error! */ }`

Comment: Glad you edited that. I was just about to try that funny << syntax on a C++11 compiler.